Linking a multilibrary project statically to libstd++?
We're building a project consisting of 2 shared libraries libProduct and libHelper. libProduct depends on libHelper. We are using a pretty new GCC toolchain (12) for the Linux build in order to leverage C++20 features in our codebase.
Now we need to ship our libraries to a user using an older Raspbian/Debian. First of all he wants to link his application to libProduct, but he also wants to swap out libHelper. The problem is that he uses a much older toolchain - the one coming with Raspbian.
We tried to link our libraries with -static-libstc++ and -static-libgcc and were hoping that this would create more or less self-containing shared libraries, but the observation is:

libHelper contains a lot of symbols from libstdc++ - that's expected
libProduct uses the libstdc++ symbols from libHelper rather than including own copies of the symbols
the user could not easily swap out libHelper with his own build because his toolchain might not provide some needed symbols in its libstdc++.

How can we solve this and achieve our goals:

We want to use a new toolchain and libstdc++
We don't want to force users to upgrade their toolchain

I know that statically linking libstdc++ to shared libraries is discouraged for various reasons. Still I would like to test it at least. But maybe there's a better alternative.

Have you considered vendoring your own copy of libstdc++?

"libProduct uses the libstdc++ symbols from libHelper" - Huh? How do you know that? What I would do is link libstdc++ dynamically, ship your copy of it along with your library, then tell them to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or -Wl,-rpath=...) to make sure it's loaded instead of the system one.

You probably can force libProduct to contain all the needed symbols by adding -lstdc++ -lgcc to the command line before -lHelper. But linking dynamically and shipping copies of these libraries seems more robust.

@HolyBlackCat libProduct contains unresolved libstdc++ symbols that are defined in libHelper. I was very surprised when I noticed that, but it somehow makes sense. That applies to symbols that are needed by both libHelper and libProduct. The symbol std::__throw_bad_array_new_length is an example.
I can only assume that the symbol is public in libstdc++.a and when the linker links libProduct it finds it in libHelper without looking at libstdc++.

@Botje we will try that. but I am bit concerned about binary compatibility if the user applications compiles with an older libstdc++ and then eventually links to our lbrand-new ibstdc++.

libstdc++ is upwards compatible. A binary built against libstdc++ version N can run with libstdc++ version N+M. This is why system updates don't break third party software.


How can we solve this and achieve our goals

There are two ways to solve this:

Link both of your libraries against libstdc++.so.6 and libgcc_s.so.1 from the newer C++20 toolchain.
Have the end-user download these versions of libstdc++ and libgcc_s.
Arrange for the end-user binary to link against these newer versions and static link time with -L/path/to/new/libs and at runtime with -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/new/libs
Link both libProduct and libHelper with -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc and hide all of the C++ symbols except the ones you want to explicitly export using a linker version script. See this answer.

Solution 1 should just work, but C++ ABI compatibility is hard, and there have been bugs in this area.
You've attempted solution 2, but it doesn't work without hiding the libstdc++ symbols.
P.S. Note that linking libstdc++ etc. statically into your libraries may have licensing implications (consult your IP lawyer).

Thanks, clever idea to use the linker script. I was compiling with visibility hidden, but of course, that does not affect symbols pulled in from static libraries.
